# How to populate a select field in Ember js

Tags: php, json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Item.all();
  }
});
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Item.reopenClass({
  all: function() {
      return $.getJSON("http://localhost/zohobus/gettable.php").then(function(response) {
        var items = [];

        response.items.forEach( function (item) {
          items.push( App.Item.create(item) );
        });

          return items;
      });
  }
});

// Part of index.html

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item.fromm}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

**I am getting Error when I have a PHP that returns JSON object

my PHP returns :**

[{"fromm":"Chennai"},{"fromm":"Chennai"},{"fromm":"Madurai"},{"fromm":"Madurai"},{"fromm":"Chennai"},{"fromm":"Chennai"}]

**In my Ember -Chrome tool i get this error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/zohobus/gettable.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: This is a CORS issue more than how to populate select field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup CORS in your server. Have a look at these resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Overview
- http://enable-cors.org/